# Acceptable to ask question which is also on drupal.org?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question on the issue section of some module on http://drupal.org/ but I would like insights and advice from a broader audience.

The question I have in mind is http://drupal.org/node/1994900, for which I got a quick but unconclusive first answer from the maintainer.

Is it acceptable to duplicate the question on Drupal Answers? To which extend is it "[about bugs workarounds](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/faq)" and hence not welcome on Drupal Answers?

Comment: It depends on the question (could you provide a link?) If it's a bug report, it's not on topic here; if it's a support question and a reasonable amount of time has passed without the maintainer(s) responding then there's more chance we can take it here. Seeing the specific question would be the first step :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can be acceptable to ask a question that's also on Drupal.org, but with the following (rough) guidelines:

- We cannot accept bug reports here.
- We cannot accept support questions for installing a specific module.
- You must wait at *least* a few days for the maintainer(s) to respond before re-posting here (there are guidelines somewhere that this should actually be 2 weeks, but I can't find them right now).

Personally I think your question falls foul of all 3 of those. To be honest, if that had been asked as an independent question on Drupal Answers I'm 99% sure it would have been closed as off-topic/un-constructive.

The most important point (for me), though, is that you only asked the question on Drupal.org *yesterday*!! Your latest comment was roughly two *hours* ago, and you haven't given the maintainer a chance to respond yet.

Sorry but I'd have to say in this case: no, that question shouldn't be duplicated on Drupal Answers.

Comment: precisely the kind of timing standards that I needed to know about, thanks.

Comment: There's nothing really set in stone (though I have seen the 2 weeks thing written somewhere before). It does seem like you've got the ear of the maintainer though, so waiting for a response would probably be your quickest way of getting an answer. If you're still struggling after a few days, or the maintainer can't help further, try to break the multiple questions down into smaller, bitesize chunks, and ask those here instead (I'm not sure if that's possible in this case, but it's normally what we'd ask people to do)

Comment: Oh, and thanks for checking here first rather than just posting the question, much appreciated :)

Comment: You're much welcome. 

I got a very valuable exchange with the maintainer of the module yesterday and today. He provided great support but could not figure out what the problem was.


As I have literally spent two full days on this, and I have no more ideas, I might give it a try here…

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden Good stuff, thanks again for having the patience to wait; hope you manage to get a decent answer